# Apple Health feature for iOS 7.1 support app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, healthkit

In my app has a Apple Health feature, it is optional and will work only if running on iOS 8.0 and above. But I want to support iOS 7.1, the Apple Health feature will not work in those device.
I can create ipa file and send to Itunes Connect, but it show error:

```
ERROR ITMS-90098: "This bundle is invalid. The key UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities contains value 'healthkit' which is incompatible with the MinimumOSVersion value of '7.1'."
```

How to make it support iOS 7.1 minimum? I see some app from Azumio and Runstatics, it is support iOS 7.1 and has Apple Health support for iOS 8.0 and above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to remove `healthkit` from the `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` array in your app's Info.plist and set the deployment SDK to iOS 7.1.